# Bootstrap modal does not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have the following bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="popupCover">
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" onClick="closeModal()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h4>Text1</h4>
    <p>Text2</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to open it with

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#myModal').modal('show')</script>
```

However, this does not work. Can anyone see the error? Thanks!

Comment: Probably you didn't load jQuery or BS js file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add jQuery and bootstrap.js files, and bootstrap script should be added after jQuery

You can see the [working pen here](http://codepen.io/vicodin/pen/yOmBJR?editors=1010)

HTML:

```
    <div class="popupCover">
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" onClick="closeModal()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>    </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h4>Text1</h4>
              <p>Text2</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: I had the jQuery and bootstrap files at the end, the resolved the problem, thanks!